# glGenFramebuffers() in Qt get 'was not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to compile a code with this call in Qt5 under Linux and I'm getting this error on compile time.

Any problem of compatibility? Any other error

I have this include:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

Comment: @devdalus I'm tried. Not is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include "gl/GLU.h"
#else
#include <glu.h>
#endif
```

When building this example on OSX and on Windows that code worked for me for finding the correct headers.

https://github.com/peteristhegreat/circles-in-a-cube/blob/master/glwidget.cpp

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`glGenFramebuffers()` is never declared in the standard GL headers, because that is a function which is not guaranteed to be even exported by the GL library on most platforms. For anything beoynd GL 1.1, the GL extension mechanism has to be used to retrieve the function pointers *at run time*. There are a couple of different [OpenGL loading libraries](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) which do all of this for you under the hood, and also provide appropriate header files so that any GL function can be used as if you were directly linking them.

You already use Qt, which provides its own GL loading mechanism, namely [QOpenGLFunctions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html) and the more modern [QAbstractOpenGLFunctions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractopenglfunctions.html) class.[This article](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-1/) provides a brief overview about the different possibilites.

Also note that Qt provides also the [QGLFramebufferObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglframebufferobject.html) class as a wrapper around GL's FBOs.